# Single-sign-on (social login) with QQ on iOS

Tags: ios, parse-platform, single-sign-on

I was able to impletement login with facebook, twitter and google plus. I want to implement login with QQ Social network and get users data.
Looks like Parse doesn't have any documentation for that, So i was working if anyone has ever done it before? even QQ's documentation is in Chinese simplified.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 3rd party SDK like [Kii](https://en.kii.com) which offers login for many social platforms. They also provide code snippets for iOS.